# CSS3 Jumpy Animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am creating a simple CSS3 slider. When doing two different property transitions, specifically a `transform: scale3d` and a `left`, the animation does the transform first, then jumps to do the left.

The jump only occurs when the animations are complete. In other words, if you continously click the next section, then the transitions are smooth.

Here is the [website](http://devdesigned.com/intrinsecus)

I made a jsFiddle and it seems to work how I want to on the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BdG4k

Essentially, this is the format of my code:

```
#slider > * {
    margin-left: -270px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
#slider .module.leftX {
    left: XX%;
    z-index: 45;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
}
```

Note: I am only using -webkit until I get it to work. Then I will add -moz and -ms.

Comment: Please isolate the problem, post the code here, and a demo to reproduce the particular issue you have.

Comment: instead of posting the website link please post your HTML, js or CSS code in http://jsbin.com or use `jsfiddle`.

Comment: I posted the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BdG4k).

Comment: thanks Aaron, can you check my suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron the problem is you are using `transform` property just for the webkit browser only.

In your js file `slider.js` you are using only chrome specific vendor prefix `-webkit`.
Try to add `-moz` prefix for Firefox also for IE.

```
$('#slider').ready( function() {
function slide(focus) {
var l1css = {
'opacity': 0.8,
'-webkit-transform': 'scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1)',
'-moz-transform': 'scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1)', /*for Firefox*/
'transform': 'scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1)', /*for IE*/
'margin-left': '-135px',
'left': '19%'
};
```

please check the working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/BdG4k/1/)**

Comment: Woops. I forgot to remove that. That is the code I used to have. At the moment, I have the same CSS however, I am only using -webkit until it works then I am going to add the -moz and -ms.

Comment: check my Demo, I've added the vendor prefix as well and now smooth animation  is working on FF and in IE.

Comment: It got better. On my website, it is still doing the same thing but only for the first click. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: I see the image over animation is working fine in FF. aah in IE its flickring due to scrollbar issue.

Comment: what if you wrap the div ID `#portfolio` inside the another div and give `position:relative` to that div?

Comment: I think I can fix the scrollbar issue for IE. Wrapping `#portfolio` with a div with `position: relative` did not do anything. I have no idea why it would do the transitions only sometimes. Is the same thing happening to you?

Comment: never face such problem.